# Selecting all attributes that have the specific value

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml:

```
<file>
  <content value="Test" />
  <content value="Empty" />
</file>
```

I want to use a transformation, but I'm having trouble to select the attribute with value of 'Test' in this example. This is the relevant part of my xslt:

```
<xsl:template match="@value">
  <xsl:attribute name="value">
    <xsl:text>succeeded</xsl:text>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

If I try to change the match to something like this `@value='Test'` or `@value['Test']` it doesn't work. I can get the element using its full path, like `//content[@value='Test']`, but I need the attribute.

Is there a way to do this replace based on the attribute value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can select attributes based on their value:

```
<xsl:template match="@value[.='Test']">
  <xsl:attribute name="value">
    <xsl:text>succeeded</xsl:text>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Here, the `.` means that the text content of the attribute is evaluated.

A complete example, embedded into an identity transform (using your XML snippet as input):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@value[.='Test']">
 <xsl:attribute name="value">
   <xsl:text>succeeded</xsl:text>
 </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Considering the other ways in which you tried to achieve this, from a content element you get to the attribute with a `/`, rather than with angle brackets:

```
<xsl:template match="content/@value">
```